# How can I use " inside send command

Tags: expect

I have used the `/usr/bin/expect` interpreter to telnet into my other system and execute some commands using send.

Telnet is successful however the problem is that I have to use the following command

```
send "unset vpn "TEST" "
```

when I run the script, it shows me the following error due to " inside send command.

```
extra characters after close-quote while executing
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [escape sequence](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/bash-prompt-escape-sequences.html), use the following,

```
send "unset vpn \"TEST\"\r"
```

or,

```
send {unset vpn "TEST"}
```

Comment: Escaping the double quotes with a backslash did not work for me. The following code would throw the error "extra characters after close-quote": send "UPDATE table SET value = '<a href=\"someurl.org\"> linktext </a>';"

Answer (score -1):

Did you try `send "unset vpn 'TEST' "`?